# What could "dipping from the company's coffers" possibly mean?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Following is excerpt from Frank Herbert's Dune:

> You have no idea how much wealth is involved, Feyd," the Baron said. "Not in your wildest imaginings. To begin, we'll have an irrevocable directorship in the CHOAM Company."
>
> Feyd-Rautha nodded. Wealth was the thing. CHOAM was the key to wealth, **each noble House dipping from the company's coffers whatever it could** under the power of the directorships.

Highlighted is the part I struggle to understand. Looks like something similar to "*each noble House taking advantage of the company's money*", but I can't find such meaning for the verb "dip". And it seems that use of the verb "dip" with the preposition "from" isn't common too.

Comment: See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dipping+into+the+company%2Cdipping+from+the+company&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdipping%20into%20the%20company%3B%2Cc0) showing that *to dip **from** the company [coffers / bank account / etc.]* has no currency whatsoever (we always *dip **into** [a source of funds]*).  Herbert is a competent writer, so perhaps he deliberately chose "unusual" (but easily-understood, for his target readership) phrasing to reflect the "unusual, exotic, other-worldly" context of his sci-fi fantasy narrative.

Comment: I think the other answers have missed the point: the usual form "dipping into" doesn't work here, because of the direct object "whatever it could". You can't say "dipping into the company's coffers whatever it could." The text as it stands sounds fine to me.

Comment: @TonyK you should make this an answer, when reading the text this phrase is usually understood implicitly, but when we pull it apart, we have all clearly missed the point. Such is the skill of Herbert in this sense! There are other language issues in the books but this one is just good inflection of the verb _into_

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In his novel Herbert make a lot of effort to portray water as the single most valuable commodity to the natives of Arrakis. This is significant to the story. Water is held as a communal resource by the Fremen and when a shar of that resource is needed, a portion is dipped *from* the cistern (collective water storage) *to* the individual.

To the galactic aristocracy, the most valuable commodity is Spice. The trade in Spice is controlled by the CHOAM company, and the wealth created by that trade is tempting for those in charge to the point that they take some for themselves.

Herbert is making an allusion between the directors of the CHOAM company taking wealth from the trading company and the Fremen taking water from their cisterns. This reinforces how water is considered more valuable than Spice to Fremen, who effectively control the supply of the latter.

"dipping from" is not a normal construct when referring to the fraudulent taking of company funds by directors. It makes sense in this context as a poetic allusion.

Comment: I''ll buy this! If you're not one already, you might have a great future as a professional literary critic! :) You haven't explicitly mentioned it, but I wouldn't be surprised if Herbert wasn't (consciously or otherwise) alluding to the extremely common collocation [***dipping from the well***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dipped+from+the+well%22) (often with the highly-relevant implication of taking too much too often, so the well runs dry).

Comment: Re *"not a normal construct"*: What is the normal construct? The opposite, *filling coffers* (hoarding money? In a somewhat unfair way?)

Comment: The normal construct when referring to the fraudulent taking of funds is *dip into* in which the referent is the subject doing the dipping and not the object dipped. The right preposition is important in the non-inflected English language.

Answer (score 51):

"Dipping into the coffers" is a standard idiom for employees or other individuals taking money  for private purposes from an organization's funds.

"Dipping from" has the same meaning but sounds a little odd to me. Searching for it found only "dipping into".

https://ludwig.guru/s/dip+into+the+coffers

Comment: I too believe this is the intended meaning, and that Herbert is creating his own idiomatic version of English, as he does throughout the book.

Comment: A _coffer_ is a strongbox, used to safely store valuables; in this case this money or gold.  Metaphorically, the sentence can mean any money the company owns, whether in a strongbox or its bank account, etc. The word coffer is now a relic word and is rarely used outside of this expression

Comment: And of course while we are on the illegal track perhaps worth mentioning the use of dip as a noun to mean a pickpocket.

Comment: @mdewey - not just limited to the noun. I would understand (in context) "dipping" to mean "pickpocketing" and in fact came her to say that!

Comment: This answer explains "dipping into the coffers", but does not do so for Herbert's "dipping from the coffers"....and therefor does not _really_ answer the question. See Stephen Webb's answer for a more complete one.

Comment: @CGCampbell I agree, and have upvoted that answer.

Comment: By analogy with dipping a spoon into a pot of soup.

Comment: @user253751: Originally, I think, something forgotten now but everyday in the past: dipping into a well or water-trough to take water.  (A *dipper* was a standard household instrument, as in the constellation the big dipper.)

Comment: Another analogy: [double-dipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dip)

Comment: Related: Walt Disney's memo of "Don't dip your pen in the company ink."

Comment: @CGCampbell this is a superior answer to the accepted one by Steven Webb, while steven explores a plausible explanation, the key is that the transitive phrasal verb here _dipping from_ is so close to that of the common English idiom _dip into (company) coffers_ that it is a clear _Herbertism_. Remember the text is not actually written in english, it is translated into english for the reader's benefit.

Answer (score 2):

A coffer is a like a box or a chest for holding valuables. Imagine a box full of gold coins. Now someone is dipping their hands in to the box, taking out handfuls of these gold coins. Of course, companies today store their money in banks. But the idiom has lived on.

Comment: Specifically, the coffers (literal or metaphorical) hold the company's _reserves_ rather than its everyday _working cash_.

Answer (score 1):

The imagery is of a ladle dipping into a liquid and taking some out. The verb "dip" is transferred from the ladle to the thing being removed.